# Subsetting dataframe based on two values in one column

Tags: r

I'm trying to subset two years of microclimate data from a larger dataset in R. I can subset one year, but am struggling to subset two years in the same operation.

This operation works fine:

```
ChamberTemp <- subset(ChamberTemp,
               subset=year=="2011",
               select=c(year,month,chamber,cat1.avg,cat2.avg,cat3.avg))
```

How do I subset by two years? i.e. 2011 and 2012

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `%in%` instead of `==` for a vector of `length` greater than 1

```
subset(ChamberTemp,
           subset=year %in% c("2011", "2012"),
           select=c(year,month,chamber,cat1.avg,cat2.avg,cat3.avg))
```

---

with `dplyr`, this can be done using

```
library(dplyr)
ChamberTemp %>%
      filter(year %in% c("2011", "2012")) %>%
      select(year, month, chamber, matches("^cat[1-3]\\.avg$"))
```